# How can I arrange numbers in this side-to-side pattern?

Tags: php, loops, numbers

I am trying to make this pattern in PHP:

```
1  2  3  4
8  7  6  5
9 10 11 12
```

I tried this, but was unsuccessful:

```
$num = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {  
    for ($j=1; $j<=5; $j++) {  
        $num = $j - $i+$num;
        echo $num.""; 
        $num--;
    }  
    echo "</br>";  
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Look at modulus operator...oo the second row is backwards, thats a bit different

Comment: What should the output look like for more than 12 numbers?  Should there always be 4 columns?  Or always 3 rows?  Something else?

Comment: (Do people really call that kind of pattern a “pyramid”? I’d say that is a Serpentine maybe, but I don’t see what is supposed to be pyramid…achical(?) about this.)

Comment: I guess doing `echo "1 2 3 4\n8 7 6 5\n9 10 11 12";` isn't fine? You could calculate what the max value of every second row is, and start to count back on indices from 0 if that makes any sense?

Comment: I can't get modulus operator for even to work as expected but here's a starting point. https://3v4l.org/R4HhB

Comment: Note: the HTML line break is `<br>`. For XHTML documents you can use `<br/>`. But `</br>` is never what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the simplest and fastest code I was able to make using two loops. It's easier with three loops and there are multiple ways to achieve this but here is the simplest one according to me.

```
<?php

$num = 1;
$change = true;
$cols = 5;
$rows = 5;

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    if (!$change) {
        $num += ($cols - 1);
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        echo $num . " ";
        if (!$change) {
            $num--;
        } else {
            $num++;
        }
    }

    if (!$change) {
        $num += ($cols + 1);
    }

    $change = !$change;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

**NOTE:** You have to define the number of columns in `$cols` variable. It will work with any case.

Comment: @JustCarty Yeah It can be a boolean too!

Answer (score 7):

I decided to opt for the [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) method to create 'rows' which I then iterate over.

```
$max = 13; // The last number
$cols = 4; // The point at which a new line will start
$arr = array_chunk(range(1, $max), $cols); // Magic ;D

// Print the data.
foreach ($arr as $key => $row) {
    // In case we are wrapping on the far side, this will prevent the row from
    // starting on the left.
    $row = array_pad($row, $cols, ' ');

    // This will reverse every other row
    $row = ($key % 2 === 0) ? $row : array_reverse($row);

    foreach ($row as $value) {
        $value = str_pad($value, strlen($max), ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "{$value} ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4 
8  7  6  5 
9 10 11 12 
        13
```

I've given you some options too so that you can change the column lengths or the number of elements you want to produce.

The string padding won't be visible in your browser unless you wrap the output in `<pre>` tags because browsers only show one space at a time.

[Code in action](https://3v4l.org/6mcAW)

Comment: Can't you combine the two foreach loops into one?

Answer (score 7):

Using a `for` loop and `range` with `array_reverse`:

https://3v4l.org/7QMGl

```
<?php

$number = 25;
$columnCount = 4;

for($i = 1, $loopCounter = 1; $i <= $number; $i = $i + $columnCount, $loopCounter++) {
    $range = range($i, $i+$columnCount - 1);

    if($loopCounter % 2 === 0) {
        $range = array_reverse($range);
    }

    foreach($range as $n) {
        echo str_pad($n, 2, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) . " ";
    }

    echo "\n";

}
```

We are increasing `$i` by the `$columnCount` on every iteration so we can always generate an array of the range of the numbers that have to be output in this row. That makes it very simple and clear if we have to reverse the numbers of the row.

`str_pad` helps us to maintain the correct spacing for e.g. single digits

*Note: You might have to swap `echo "\n";` for `echo "<br>";` if you are looking at the output in a browser.*

Comment: `$columnCount = -1;` generates a strange result :)

Comment: The only other person who padded the numbers with spaces, as per OP's question! +1

Answer (score 5):

Just to add a short version...

```
$columns = 4;
$rows = 3;
foreach ( array_chunk(range(1,$columns * $rows), $columns) as $row => $line )    {
    echo implode(" ", ($row % 2 == 0 )?$line:array_reverse($line) )."<br />";
}
```

The idea being to use `range` to create the numbers into an array and then use `array_chunk` to split it into lines.  Then use `implode()` to output the lines - with the odd number lines reversed using `array_reverse()`.

Comment: @JustCarty - short code isn't necessarily better.  It's also isn't usually quicker.

Comment: Very true, the other thing I noticed that your solution doesn't get is the padding of the smaller numbers. Aside from that "Great minds, think alike" and all that ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is super easy and you don't need to use array functions, just some math:

```
$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
        if ($row % 2 === 0) {
            // $row * $cols + 1 gives you first number for that row
            // e.g. for row number 2 you get 2 * 4 + 1 = 9
            $num = $row * $cols + 1 + $col;
        } else {
            // ($row + 1) * $cols gives you last number for that row
            // e.g. for row number 1 you get (1 + 1) * 4 = 8
            $num = ($row + 1) * $cols - $col;
        }
        echo sprintf('%2d ', $num);
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo on IDEONE](https://www.ideone.com/fHgRGA)

Answer (score 3):

The following code will divide a range from 1 to 12 in chunks of 4. It will then walk through those chunks and print them forwards or backwards alternatively.

```
$forward = true;
array_walk(array_chunk(range(1, 12), 4), function ($a) use (&$forward) {
    echo $forward ? implode(' ', $a)  . '<br />' : implode(' ', array_reverse($a)) . '<br />';
    $forward = $forward ? false : true;
});
```

Or you could use a `for``loop:

```
for ($i = 4; $i <= 12; $i += 4) {
    echo (($i / 4) % 2) == 0 ? implode(' ', range($i, $i - 3)) . '<br />' : implode(' ', range($i - 3, $i)) . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another simple solution just by extending the OP's method. You can try it out with different row and column sizes by changing values for first 2 variables.

```
<?
    $row_count = 3; //You can change this value depending to how many rows do you want to print
    $column_count = 4; //You can change this value depending to how many columns will be at each row

    $result = ''; //Variable to hold the output to print
    $num = 0; //Variable to hold temporary value for each element
    for ($i=1; $i<=$row_count; $i++) {
        //Every row
        for ($j=1; $j<=$column_count; $j++) {  
            //Every column
            if($i % 2 == 1) {
                //If row number is odd, increment the value starting from maximum element of previous row
                $num = (($i - 1) * $column_count) + $j;
            }
            else {
                //If row number is even, decrement the value starting from maximum element of current row
                $num = ($i * $column_count) - ($j - 1);
            }
            //Add calculated number to output with  extra space if it's length is short
            $result .= $num . addSpace($row_count, $column_count, $num); 
        }  
        $result .= '</br>';  
    }

    //Method to add spaces after number to provide a matrix-like template for the output
    function addSpace($row_count, $column_count, $current_number) {
        $space = ' ';
        $max_number = $row_count * $column_count;
        $max_length = strlen($max_number);
        $current_number_length = strlen($current_number);
        for($digit=$current_number_length; $digit<$max_length; $digit++) {
            $space .= '&nbsp;';
        }
        return $space;
    }

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                font-family: Courier;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <? echo $result; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, the only downfall I can see is that if we have 3 or more digits then `$result .= $num.($num < 9 ? '&nbsp; ' : ' ')` won't add enough space.

Comment: @JustCarty Thank you, edited the code and added a dynamic space count calculation method.

Answer (score 2):

```
$number = 12;
$elements_per_row = 4;
$left_to_right = true;
$processed_number_count = 0;
$result_array = [];
$temp = [];
for ($i=1; $i<=$number; $i++) {
    $temp[] = $i;
    $processed_number_count++;
    if ($processed_number_count === $elements_per_row) {
        $processed_number_count = 0;
        if ($left_to_right) {
            $result_array[] = $temp;
        } else {
            $result_array[] = array_reverse($temp);
        }
        $left_to_right = !$left_to_right;
        $temp = [];
    }
}

var_dump($result_array);
```

Then simply foreach $result_array to print desired pattern

This can be used variably for many other patterns which use same rule by modifying  $number and $elements_per_row

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
bool forwardReverse = false;
int width = 4;
string line = "";
for (int i = 1; i < maxValue; i++)
{
    if (i % width == 0)
    {
        forwardReverse = !forwardReverse;
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    line = "";
    }

    if (forwardReverse)
    {
        line = line + i;        
    }
    else
    {
        line = i + line
    }
}
```

Every time you get to the end of a row (width) the Boolean flag changes and the order that new values are added is switched between appending and prepending.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much Nigel's answer, walk through a chunked range, echoing out each row, reversing every other:

```
<?php
$cols = 4;
$rows = 3;
array_walk(
    array_chunk(
        range(1, $rows*$cols),
        $cols
    ),
    function($v, $k) {
        if($k%2)
            $v = array_reverse($v);
        echo implode(' ', $v), "\n";
    }
);
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
8 7 6 5
9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code. I used `array_map` function to properly add padding before numbers:

```
<?php

$min = 1;
$max = 12;
$cols = 4;

$chunkedArray = array_chunk(range($min, $max), $cols);

foreach ($chunkedArray as $index => $row) {
    $dataToShow = $index % 2 == 0 ? $row : array_reverse($row);
    $dataToShow = array_map(function($element) use ($max) {
        return str_pad($element, strlen($max), ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }, $dataToShow);

    echo implode(' ', $dataToShow) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4
 8  7  6  5
 9 10 11 12
```

Working example: **[CLICK!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73dcc9b9fc5356d316d393a4a5c8bf8bcb94159c)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   $flag = false;
   result($numbers, $flag);

   function printMe(&$array2){
    foreach($array2 as $index => $value){
    echo $value."   ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
   }

   function reverse(&$num, $flag)
   {
    if($flag){
    array_reverse($num, true);
    }
    $flag = false;
   }
    function add(&$array){
          $array[0] += 4;     
          $array[1] += 4; 
          $array[2] += 4; 
          $array[3] += 4; 
    }
    function result($numbers, $flag){
        for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
        {
            reverse($numbers, $flag);
            printMe($numbers);
            add($numbers);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I like using functions because they make it easy for any later changes. With this code you can print as many lines by just changing the loop counter

Comment: Your explanation is meant to go inside the answer, not posted as a comment.